# url rewrite not working in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am working in cakephp.i have done rewrite url for all forms and links. and i have done server side validation through model.
but when server side error is generate then url rewrite not working

one form i have done urlrewrite  for that like

```
Router::connect('/employers/edit-securitydetail/:id', array(
    'controller' => 'fj_employers',
    'action'     => 'editSecurityDetail',
    'id'         => '[0-9]+'
));
```

then i can access this controller using this url `employers/edit-securitydetail/1`

when server side error is generate then url change to `fj_employers/editSecurityDetail/1`

can anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

Use below:

```
Router::connect('/fj_employers/editSecurityDetail/:id', array(
    'controller' => 'fj_employers',
    'action'     => 'editSecurityDetail'),
    array('id' => '[0-9]*')
);
```

This will fix the problem. Actually the problem is in url rewriting correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a second route in that looks like this:

```
Router::connect('/employers/editSecurityDetail/:id', array(
    'controller' => 'fj_employers',
    'action'     => 'editSecurityDetail',
    'id'         => '[0-9]+'
));
```

or maybe this:

```
Router::connect('/fj_employers/editSecurityDetail/:id', array(
    'controller' => 'fj_employers',
    'action'     => 'editSecurityDetail',
    'id'         => '[0-9]+'
));
```

Comment: i don't have problem with url rewrite.
My problem is that when server side validation error message is display then url will change /employers/editSecurityDetail/1 to 
fj_employers/editSecurityDetail/1 

Thanks for your respose